# ASP.NET MVC Authentication by Using FormsAuthenticationTicket (may be)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a PHP guy but am in the process of making a log-in page in ASP.NET MVC4. I am expecting to store the ID, Username and Roles of the user in session. So far what I am doing is as follows. If I am correct it saves the cookie with the username.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.UserLoginModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Models.User u = new Models.User();
            if (u.IsValid(user.Username, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, user.RememberMe);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Accounts");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

My interest is to store more information and control validation time. I was advised and **asked to use**  `FormAuthenticationTicket` class. I replaced `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, user.RememberMe);` with

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket
(
    1, 
    user.Username, 
    DateTime.Now, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
    false, 
    "Some User Data", 
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
);
Response.Cookies.Add
(
    new HttpCookie
    (
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
        FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
    )
);
```

It looks cool, I didn't test it though, has flexibility. But problem is how I could receive this information.

How can I get these information back and determine if the user is logged in and also other necessary information saved inside the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I will appreciate any comments on making a custom log-in form in ASP.NET MVC. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you would any ticket:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
var ticketInfo = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
```

Since it's a security ticket, if you don't need to access the information from client JavaScript, also set HttpOnly to true.  This means the cookie is only accessible on the server.

Comment: How would you apply that in razor pages, assume you need to pass the a second ticket from client to services and you make use of ticketInfo.UserData